# An AppBarButton is randomly fired after the App is compiled for releasing

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I'm developing a new App with *VS 2013* for *Windows Phone 8.1* (***WinRT***) and I'm getting desperate that sometimes works and sometimes doesn't work. I need to compile N times the same project to make that one element works. This is my code.

**XAML:**

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar x:Name="appBar">
        <AppBarButton x:Name="btnNew" Icon="Add" IsCompact="False" Label="new result" Click="btnNew_Click"/>
        <AppBarButton x:Name="btnShare" IsCompact="False" Label="share" Click="btnShare_Click">
            <AppBarButton.Icon>
                <BitmapIcon UriSource="Assets/AppBar/share.png"/>
            </AppBarButton.Icon>
        </AppBarButton>
        <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton x:Name="menuPersonal" Label="profile" Click="menuPersonal_Click"/>
            <AppBarButton x:Name="menuTips" Label="tips" Click="menuTips_Click"/>
            <AppBarButton x:Name="menuHelp" Label="help" Click="menuHelp_Click"/>
            <AppBarButton x:Name="menuAbout" Label="about us" Click="menuAbout_Click"/>
        </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

**C#:**

```
private void menuTips_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(Tips));
}

private void menuPersonal_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(Personal));
}

private void btnShare_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(Share), txtLast.Text);
}

private void btnNew_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(OcrResult));
}

private void menuHelp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(Help));
}

private void menuAbout_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(About));
}
```

The problem ONLY happens in the *Profile menu* option.

When it's not working, VS shows me this kind of message after I did click on the button.

*The thread 0xb08 has exited with code 259 (0x103).*

*The thread 0x1b0 has exited with code 259 (0x103).*

What I have already tried:

- Changed the name of the Class that I need to load.
- Re-created the Frame.
- Moved the location of the item.
- Changed the name of the function.
- Created one function for all options (it doesn't matter if I add a breakpoint, I cannot know why it's not working).
- Tried the Tapped Event (same problem).
- Added several try catches everywhere.

I should clarify that this problem happens even in another forum where I'm calling the same Frame and it doesn't open it there too.

Even any breakpoint doesn't work when the App gave that error. I'd like to know if someone has experimented with this issue and if someone has lived it perhaps someone could so kind to give me an idea of how to fix it.

Thank you for your worthy knowledge and time.

Comment: And do other buttons work - is navigation to pages successful? Can you check in debug mode if constructor of page *Personal* is called? Also - does frame.NavigationFailed event get called?

Comment: All buttons work with exception of that one and sometimes all of them work but when someone failed is just that. The other frame when it doesn't work, it never opens and the menu is just closed like there's no code.

Comment: How does you *Profile* page look like? When you navigate in first button to *Help* page instead of *Profile* one - does it work ok?

Comment: Yes, all buttons work and sometimes when I compile the other one.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's probable that there is a problem in your *Profile* page - ca you show its code?

Comment: I'll come back in half an hour and I'll share it :), thanks but as I told you when the App gives that error, it doesn't matter if I add a break point in the button it doesn't work and when it works it works the break point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the problem was related to these libraries:]
https://www.nuget.org/packages/WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization/
http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/

After I replaced the graph with another one, everything is working. I recommend to everyone who uses these libraries to take care of them.

Answer (score 0):

I are you sure, there is no problem either in constructor or in ONNavigatedTo event on the target page?
I know it sounds crazy but try to put the Frame.Navigate to dispatcher block like:
     `this.Frame.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, new Windows.UI.Core.DispatchedHandler(()=> Frame.Navigate(typeof(SomePage))));`

even if it

doesn't need to be invoked on UI thread...